# How to configure docker for windows to correctly route via cisco AnyConnect with split tunnels

Tags: vpn, routing, docker

I am running Docker Desktop 4.6.1 on Windows 10.
I am connected to a vpn via Cisco AnyConnect 4.10.02086.
AnyConnect has several secured routes defined,
e.g. 10.1.160.0/24
Non-Secured routes is defined as 0.0.0.0/0

I can ping a host on the vpn from powershell
e.g. ping 10.1.160.167

However if I run a docker container and try to ping from within the container I get
  `Destination Host Unreachable`

I can ping 8.8.8.8 from within the container